# Filesize varies in chromes network-panel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to analyze the performance of my web-app with Chrome DevTools. So I was looking at timings under "Inspect Element" > "Network". While comparing localhost to the same page on the web, I noticed that the size of several .js-Files varied significantly, i.e. one minified .js was shown with 4.5kb on the web and 13.9kb on localhost.
However, when I right-clicked these entries in nw-panel to "Save", I got identical files with 14kb.

So where do these variations come from?  *(BTW, Firefox shows that file also with14kb when access on the web!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your web server has deflate compression for plaintext files enabled while your local server doesn't. (`mod_deflate` in apache)

Compare the `Content-Encoding` headers of both variants.

Comment: I'm using exactly the same server-config in both cases. content-type for that file is `content-type: application/javascript`

Comment: @mbaas Sorry, I meant Content-Encoding

Comment: Thank you - you are right - the one from the web comes deflated whereas the local one isn't. I'm not using Apache or other well-know stuff, I'm using MiServer (a web-server written in APL) and the one thing where both systems differ is that one had a "Production"-flag whereas the other works in Debug-mode. I would not have thought that this would also impact the encoding - will get in touch with the devs now. Thanks!